# Weird date issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list with delivery date column. I have created a table to display current week and next week delivery items using javascript. Everything works fine but for couple of team members Thursday delivery items are displaying in Wednesday cell and Friday items in Thursday cell.

I am not sure why it is happening. Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code. Added alerts to verify data, I am wondering why in second and third alerts sunday is showing Monday date and in third alert monday is showing Tuesday date. Added alert messages at the bottom. Please advice.

```
today = moment();

sundayDate = new Date(today.startOf('week'));
sundayShortDate = sundayDate.toLocaleDateString();
sundayTitle = getFormattedDate(sundayDate);

window.alert("sundayDate ::"+sundayDate+"");

monDate = new Date(sundayDate.setDate(sundayDate.getDate() + 1));
monSDate = monDate.toLocaleDateString();
monTitle = getFormattedDate(monDate);

window.alert("sundayDate ::"+sundayDate+"; monDate::"+monDate+"");

tueDate = new Date(monDate.setDate(monDate.getDate() + 1));
tuesSDate = tueDate.toLocaleDateString();
tueTitle = getFormattedDate(tueDate);

window.alert("sundayDate ::"+sundayDate+"; monDate::"+monDate+"; tueDate::"+tueDate+"");

First window alert:
sundayDate ::Sun Aug 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Second Alert:
sundayDate ::Mon Aug 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time); monDate::Mon Aug 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Third Alert:
sundayDate ::Mon Aug 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time); monDate::Tue Aug 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time); tueDate::Tue Aug 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: `sundayDate.setDate(sundayDate.getDate() + 1)` changes `sundayDate` to Monday's date.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the dates, you need to make copies before calling `setDate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already commented, you are mutating the dates with calls to `setDate()`.

As you already use moment, don't switch back to Date objects, but stick to moment objects.

For example:

```js
let today = moment();

let fmt = "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY";
let sunDate = today.startOf('week');
let sunShortDate = sunDate.format(fmt);
let monDate = sunDate.clone().add(1, "day");
let monShortDate = monDate.format(fmt);
let tueDate = monDate.clone().add(1, "day");
let tueShortDate = tueDate.format(fmt);

console.log({ sunShortDate, monShortDate, tueShortDate });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Just like `Date` objects, also `moment` objects are mutable, and so you should call `clone` first before calling `add`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.I used clone and it worked but my main question is why Wednesday delivery items displaying in Tuesday cell and Thursday items are displaying on Wednesday Cell.

Comment: The reason is that you mutate your dates by using `sundayDate.setDate()`: this *mutates* `sundayDate`, so that it no longer is a Sunday. Similar things happen with the other date object on which you call `setDate()`. You make them shift one day by that.

Comment: I was using ShortDate for adding delivery items to table. I am not updating ShortDate using SetDate. So I am wondering what causing the issue. Only couple of users facing this issue. remaining other users including me not facing this issue.

Comment: That is not what you have in your question's code: there you alert `sundayDate`, which you see is incremented with one day between the first and second alert. And the explanation for that is what I wrote above.

Comment: Ok. Let me ask my second question.I have a SharePoint list with delivery date column. I have created a table to display current week and next week delivery items using javascript. Everything works fine but for couple of team members Thursday delivery items are displaying in Wednesday cell and Friday items in Thursday cell.
I am not sure why it is happening. Please advice.

Comment: This most probably has to do with mix up of displaying local time versus UTC time. You always need to take care you choose one of both, and then stick with that decision all the way. But if you have particular code that reproduces that, then ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

You set `sundayDate` to `sundayDate.setDate(sundayDate.getDate() + 1)`
You should do:
`monDate = new Date(sundayDate.getDate() + 1);`

P.S.
I'm not sure if mixing moment.js and js Date is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. monDate = new Date(sundayDate.getDate() + 1) gives wrong date. For Monday I used clone.
monDate = new Date(sundayDate.clone().setDate(sundayDate.getDate() + 1));